# Proxy API request using React Router

Tags: reactjs, api, proxy, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to set up a proxy to handle GET and POST requests. I have done this many times without using react-router in prior react apps and it's works perfect, however since this app uses react-router it fails.

The proxy isn't working, instead trying to do the call on the localhost domain:

```
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://localhost:3001/api/call"
```

I am not doing anything fancy with my react router:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here is the proxy (in setupProxy.js):

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api/call', { target: "http://www.domain.com.au/", changeOrigin: true } ));
};
```

Here is a sample of how it's used:

```
add(data) {

    this.setState({button: "loading"})

    fetch('/api/call', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(res => this.setState({success: res.ok}))
    .catch(err => this.setState({success: false}))

}
```

Do I need to do anything extra to make this work when using react-router?

Comment: `react-router` only handles the routing portion of your App and determines what content should be shown depending on the current route. Is the proxy within a component?

Comment: It's used in a function, I have added a sample to the original question.

Comment: Ah I think I might have found your solution on the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: Are you able to point to which part could be the solution? I have read these and can't seem to find out any additional help. As mentioned this has worked perfectly in the past and only when using react-router has the issue appeared.

Comment: Just saw your reply. Could you try using the `exact` parameter on both routes? It's possible that react-router might be interfering with your proxy

Comment: Also try changing your proxy to be only `/api`

Comment: Mm I tried using this with your suggestions, and then also created a basic create-react-app with no router (all with the same error). I think it was a coincidence of using this particular API service and using it in routes for the first time that got me confused. I'm currently investigating to see if the error is with the API service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question **is working** without issues. When the proxy request returns an error it displays this as coming from localhost, not from the proxy url.

Answer (score 0):

this proxy we use in dev mode, its dont work in production build. If you have to work with dev mode, your request is `POST http://www.domain.com.au/api/call` if you need send your req directly to `http://www.domain.com.au/` then make your proxy

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', {
    target: "http://www.domain.com.au/",
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
                '^/api/': '/', // remove base path
            }
    } ));
};
```

Now, you can fetch("/api/mydata") to `GET http://www.domain.com.au/mydata`